# AngularJS: how to implement server-side or client-side authentication?

Tags: express, angularjs

I want to authenticate an AngularJS app, it is running on top of Node.js and Express.js backend with Jade templates.

I thought of the following strategies:

1) server side authentication - store credentials in session variables and redirect the user to the AngularJS app, the problem: how to pass the credentials to AngularJS? (I can render those as Jade variables, but how can I read them with AngularJS?), also, how to handle session expiry ?

2) client side authentication - do the authentication with AJAX calls and get the credentials,
the problems: how to handle 'session' expiry and how to remember users so they won't have to login every time the app starts ?

any insights may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up authentication for a Angular.js application isn't any different then setting it up for any other website. You post your username and password to the server and it will set a session/cookie if your credentials are correct. To get data (in your case crdentials) from the server you use the same techniques you always use with Javascript. Xhr, websockets, render values in a text field, ...